# Why camel-case fields are not recognized by API?

Tags: java, json, api, rest, spring-mvc

I have defined my **request class** like:

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SampleRequest {

    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;
    
    private String middleName;

    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;
}
```

**Controller** as:

```java
    @PostMapping(path = "mydetails",  consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public DeferredResult<DetailsResponse> saveMyDetails(@Validated @RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest) {

        // some logic here

        return detailsResponse;
    }
```

When I'm sending my **request from Postman** as:

```json
{
   "firstName":"John",
   "middleName":"For",
   "lastName":"Doe",
}
```

the value of all fields received at controller is null. Upon investigating, I found that it is somehow not accepting the fields in camel-case, rather it is accepting with underscore. So, I tried hitting the API with below format and it worked:

```json
{
   "first_name":"John",
   "middle_name":"For",
   "last_name":"Doe",
}
```

So, why it is like this? Whatever fashion we defined in our request class, it should be same while sending the request from Postman or from app side. Why is it only working when I have to send with underscore instead of camel-case?

Comment: That depends on the configurations of the underlying json library. Looks like you are using spring-boot, which normally comes with jackson. Edit your question to show the configuration of `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: So you mean to say that I should use @JsonProperty("firstName") and @JsonProperty("lastName") explicitly on each field whichever I want it to be in camel-case? If that solves the issue then it's fine. Thanks.
But where can I check the configuration of ObjectMapper in my project?

Comment: @JohnSmith: [see here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-customize-jackson-objectmapper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this for any field you want to in your request class:

```
@JsonProperty("firstName")
private string firstName;

@JsonProperty("middleName")
private string middleName;

@JsonProperty("lastName")
private string lastName;
```

Comment: Thanks, It solved the issue without much hassle. I didn't touch other fields in the request class because those are being used by other people. But I need to learn this configuration where can I set things properly without these annotations workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try to annotate your class (`SampleRequest`) with:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategies.LowerCamelCaseStrategy.class)
```